# Office365 Auditing - specifically viewing devices logged in to accounts

Tags: email, exchange, powershell, office365

We have some clients who work with government contracts, and some of their requests has been to being able to audit accounts and seeing where they logged in from based on IP.

Is there a way to do this?

I am attempting the following via powershell but I am not sure if this is the way to go.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox"} | Set-Mailbox -AuditEnabled $true
```

And for viewing:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox"} | Set-Mailbox -AuditOwner MailboxLogin
```

Am I going about this the right way to view IPs with time stamps and when they logged in and with what devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Azure subscription, you have access to these details.

---

To examine the devices and applications from which a specific user connected to a mailbox in Office 365:

1. In the Security & Compliance Center, choose Reports > View reports.
2. Under Auditing, choose Azure AD reports.
3. In the Azure management
   portal, on the Active Directory tab, choose the name of your
   organization.
4. Under your organization name, choose Users. Locate the
   user you want to investigate and choose the username.
5. On the user page, choose Devices.
6. In the View drop-down list, select Devices and applications from which the 
   user has signed in. This will provide details, such as the version of client 
   used to sign in, and the last sign-in time, IP address, and location of the 
   user.

---

For more details, you may check this [Microsoft TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219044.aspx).